# Gaming Questions of the Week #2

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, blog, question-of-the-week

So last weeks gaming question of the week [successfully led to a blog post](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/minecraft/small-world-not-quite). Of course, an important part of Question of the Week is the "week" part, so we need another one. Post your suggestions here.

### Sample Questions

- Last week's question - [Minecraft's World Size](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/minecrafts-world-size)
- [Is it possible to finish Deus Ex 2 without killing a single enemy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19502/is-it-really-possible-to-finish-deus-ex-without-actively-killing-a-single-enemy)
- [What is the optimal position of a sentry gun?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/what-is-the-optimal-position-of-a-sentry-gun)

If you want to nominate either of the two sample questions for this week, post them as an answer. Feel free to nominate any other questions you feel are deserving also.

Comment: @failbadp, this needs [status-completed](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/qotw/qotw-2-missingno) :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Pokemon (Red or Gold) Secret pokemon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19638/10)

Someone should help me bring back these fond memories of **Missingno**

[image]

Comment: The answer here was really interesting because it talked about how bugs occur and how they effect the gameplay.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to take into account the game/tag popularity/trend so Minecraft question was a good choice last week IMHO.

This week I suggest to go with Starcraft one. Even if personally I don't play neither like that game, many do so, what about:

- [Why do some players build their buildings in a line (towards the entrance of their base)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19540/730)

it seems smart.

Comment: I like the idea of avoiding another Minecraft question since that game was used last week.